# Try to pass argument to C function in Nasm elf64 but it return SIGFPE error

Tags: c, arguments, 64-bit, nasm

I try to implement the C sqrt function in Nasm elf64, it works correctly without argument (with the value of "a" define in the function), but when I try to pass an argument to this function ,the code return an error "Stopped reason: SIGFPE".

Here's my code

The c function

```
int le_sqrt(int a) {
   int n=1;
   int number = a;
   for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
       n=(n+number/n)/2;  
   }
   return n; 
}
```

The nasm program

```
bits 64
global _start
extern le_sqrt 

_start:
    mov rbp,9 ;argument 
    push rbp ;same argument push
    call le_sqrt ; my c function

    mov rax,60 ;exit program
    mov rsi,0
    syscall
```

Comment: It seems that you are using the wrong calling convention. Which OS and which command line instruction do you use to compile the C program? See here for a list of calling conventions on amd64: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#List_of_x86_calling_conventions

Comment: I used ubuntu wsl 64 bits. For compiling, I compile my c function in .o and my nasm elf64 in .o, then y mixed the twiced.     gcc -c sqrt.c -o sqrt.o         |         nasm -f elf64 test.asm -o test.o   | ld -o app sqrt.o test.o

Comment: If an answer solved your problem, please accept it.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to call `le_sqrt(9)` with System V AMD64 ABI calling convention, do this:

```
_start:
    mov rdi,9
    call le_sqrt
```

Answer (score 1):

`SIGFPE` usually happens when you divide a number by `0`. In your assembly program, you are using `mov rbp, 9` for passing an argument to c function, which might be wrong in your case. It becomes obvious since you're getting `SIGFPE`. See [Microsoft calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#Microsoft_x64_calling_convention) and [System V ABI calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI) (for 64-bit). For 32-bit, follow [these calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#List_of_x86_calling_conventions).